# $X$ is normal space if and only if continuous function onto $[0,1]$ exists

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space.  Then $X$ is normal if and only if for every pair of disjoint closed sets $A,B \subset X$, there exists a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x \in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in B$.

($\Rightarrow$)  Assuming that $X$ is normal, we have for disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ that there exist disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $A \subset U$ and $B \subset V$.  I am thinking that we need to construct a function from $X$ onto $[0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x \in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in B$ and somehow show that it is continuous using the open sets $U$ and $V$.

($\Leftarrow$)  Assume that there exists a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = 0 $ for all $x \in A$ and $f(x)=1$ for all $x \in B$.  I am thinking of using the fact that since $f$ is continuous, for any open set $V \subset [0,1]$, we have $f^{-1}(V)$ open in $X$.  Then I want to find two open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $[0,1]$ such that $A \subset f^{-1}(U)$ and $B \subset f^{-1}(V)$ and $f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}(V) = \emptyset$.  But I am having trouble finding such $U$ and $V$. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you know Urysohn's lemma?

Answer (score 2):

For $\Rightarrow$, consider [Urysohn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn%27s_lemma). This is the hard part, I think.

For $\Leftarrow$, consider $f^{-1}\big([0,1/3)\big)$ and $f^{-1}\big((2/3,1]\big)$ and use the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Do you meant $f^{-1}([0, 1/3))$?

Comment: I am still stuck on the reverse direction.

Comment: We know that since $f$ is continuous, for every open set $V \subset [0,1]$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.  We also know that $A \subset f^{-1}([0,1/3))$ and $B \subset f^{-1}((2/3,1])$. However $[0,1/3)$ and $(2/3,1]$ are not open sets.

Comment: You are correct in that it should be $f^{-1}\big([0,1/3)\big)$. $[0,1/3)$ and $(2/3,1]$ are open in $[0,1]$.

Comment: got it, thanks!

Comment: How do we know that $f^{-1}([0,1/3)) \cap f^{-1}((2/3,1]) = \emptyset $?  It seems like it should be true because $f$ is continuous, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: This does not have to do with continuity. $x \in f^{-1}\big([0,1/3)\big)$ iff $f(x)\in[0,1/3)$. Similarly, $x \in f^{-1}\big((2/3,1]\big)$ iff $f(x)\in (2/3,1]$. It cannot be that $f(x)\in [0,1/3)$ and $f(x)\in(2/3,1]$, simultaneously, so the intersection must be empty.

Comment: I thought this was true only for one-to-one functions, not necessarily in general.

Comment: This is true for 'single-valued' functions, in general (ie, for each $x$ in the domain, $f(x)$ is a single value).